# Does Android use String compacting behind the scenes?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, profiling, memory-profiling

I've analyzed the memory of my Android app on Android **28** and found most of it is used for just strings:

[image]

Obviously i'm looking for ways of decreasing of memory consumption. So the idea is to migrate from UTF-16 strings to UTF-8 to save 50% roughly.

I was pretty impressed how String compacting works in Java 9:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string

Since i can see `byte[]` (not `char[]`) allocations i wonder if Android uses the same behind the scene. If not, what are potential problems with doing pretty the same in app scope (have `my.app.String` class with compact impl).

PS. I've profiled it on Android **24** and i can see `char[]` are allocated:

[image]

Does it mean String compacting was actually implemented/enabled after Android 24?

Comment: How did you compile your app? For which Java version?

Comment: it's android app (i've updated my question), targeted to Android 28. Compiled with Gradle and Android SDK, written in Kotlin.

Comment: And which Java version did you specify in Gradle? If you set it to Java 9, wouldn't it be obvious that it uses String compacting? What's in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Java 9 is not supported in Android AFAIK. So it's Java 8 used